# Swift: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value While updating a Label

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, option-type

I have a UILabel inside a modelviewcontroller. 
What i want to do is change its text on a certain point of my code. The problem is it works in the first point and stops working on the second one, throwing the following error:

```
unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

I found other questions on the same error but those solutions are not working for me. Maybe I am doing something wrong with the optionals.

Here is the code of my model view controller:

```
import UIKit

class CheckInViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var test: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    print("Appeared")
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("scanViewController") as! ScanViewController

    test.text = "Here it works" // FIRST POINT WORKS AND CHANGES THE LABEL

    if let qrCode = vc.qrCode{ // vc.qrCode IS AN OPTIONAL

        qrRead(qrCode)
        vc.qrCode = nil
    }


}

func qrRead(qrCode: String) {

    print(qrCode)

    test.text = "Here it doesnt work" // HERE IT STOPS WORKING
}
```

Comment: check your outlet is properly attached or not?

Comment: @EICaptain if it wasn't attached the initial set wouldn't work.

Comment: @Woodstock is right. However is correctly attached

Comment: Is this really your full unmodified code? What exactly is vc.qrCode?

Comment: @Tapani In ScanViewController I scan a QR Code. vc.qrCode in an option string where I put the string I read in the QR Code. Here in CheckInViewController I'm trying to check if vc.qrCode has a value to use it for an http request

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the `vc.qrCode` to `nil` directly after passing it to the `func qrRead(qrCode: String)` function.

Remove this line: `vc.qrCode = nil` and check if the error persists.

If it does not, as I suspect, nil the var out elsewhere.

Remember using if let, you actually access the underlying instance, not a copy.

**As such, when you set vc.qrCode to nil, you are ALSO setting qrCode to nil which causes issues when you try to print it in the qrRead function**

Example:

```
class Person {

}

var a:Person? = Person()

if let some = a
{
    print(unsafeAddressOf(some))
    print(unsafeAddressOf(a!))
}
```

Prints:

```
0x0000000005011ed0

0x0000000005011ed0
```

Which shows they are the **same** instance in memory.

Comment: I agree with WoodStock's answer. Never try to set the value to nil inside if let. Coming to your question, you haven't called super.viewDidAppear(animated: animated). Try adding that and check if the problem persists.